# adding an xml design as a new view that I can then add to other layouts when needed

Tags: android, xml, view, android-custom-view

I made the following xml document as a custom designed button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/CBN_LinearLayout"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/redcirclenotify"
        android:src="@drawable/rednotify"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CBV_texview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/checkorder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CBV_textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CBV_textview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/blankstring" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CBV_textview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/blankstring" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to know if I can make this an accessible view in the custom section in the ADK without having to create a custom class. If I must create a custom class extending view is there a way to reference this layout for the specifics as I would rather not program it in the class.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always refernce this layout whereevr required .just include this layout in ur other layout xml whereevr required like this:

```
 <include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:layout_y="0px"
    layout="@layout/ur custom layout" />
```

Can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use inflation for it in java file.

```
final LayoutInflater lyInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_xml, null);
```

Or you can [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) it in xml file.